# Java - Execute Command using Runtime.getRuntime()

Tags: java, cmd, command-prompt

I have the following command which is executed successfully via cmd terminal which will return a String output

```
type "/*path to key*/" | "/*path to custom exe file*/" key sign /*userid*/

      where /* -- */ are placeholders
```

I tried to execute the same command through java but unsuccessful

Following are the ways I tried

**Way 1**

```
String[] cmd1 = new String[] {"type", "myPathToKey"};

String[] cmd2 = new String[] {"myPathToExe", "key", "sign", userid};

Process pro1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1, null, new File("executionDirectory"));
InputStream input = pro1.getInputStream();

Process pro2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd2, null, new File("executionDirectory"));
OutputStream output = pro2.getOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(input, output);
output.close();
List<String> result = IOUtils.readLines(pro2.getInputStream());
System.out.println(result);
```

**Way 2**

```
String[] cmd1 = new String[] {"type", "myPathToKey", "|", "myPathToExe", "key", "sign", userid};

Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd1, null, new File("executionDirectory"));

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

For both ways I get following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "type" (in directory "executionDirectory"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.rntbci.symbiose.JMeterBatchConfiguration.EHorizonSign.main(Test.java:33)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

How can this issue be fixed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `type` is a `cmd` internal, not a program that you can execute with `Runtime#exec`.

Comment: @dan1st, Is there an alternate to execute the type cmd in java

Comment: Just read the file directly (without exec)?

Comment: In Windows CMD `type {filename}` copies the contents of the file to stdout, like `cat` in Unix. For sane programs, reading the contents of a file via a pipe is the same as reading the contents of the file directly: try `mypathtoexe <file ...` in CMD and if that works use `ProcessBuilder` with `.redirectInput` to do the equivalent.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Could you share a sample code for reference please?